# SQL: Exclude duplicates on same date

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a database with the following columns. (there are a few other time stamp columns I excluded for ease of reading.

Job
DispDate
Description
Who

The job column will have duplicates based on date. For example the first job of the day will be "0001-A" and the next job of the same day will be "0002-A". This number will go continue to add 1 until midnight when the job number resets to "0001-A" again.

I need a SQL query to exclude the duplicates on the same day. If you look at the table below, the rows with asterixis (**) should be excluded from the query.

| Job | dispdate | description | Who |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001-A | 2023-01-01 | *String* | User |
| 0002-A | 2023-01-01 | *String* | User |
| **0002-A | 2023-01-01 | *String* | User** |
| 0001-A | 2023-01-02 | *String* | User |
| 0002-A | 2023-01-02 | *String* | User |
| 0003-A | 2023-01-02 | *String* | User |
| 0001-A | 2023-01-03 | *String* | User |
| **0001-A | 2023-01-03 | *String* | User |

This is the current SQL Query I have and need the duplicate exclusions added to.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.job, t.dispdate, t.disptime, th.moddate, th.modtime, th.description, th.who
FROM Trip_History as th
LEFT JOIN Trips t ON (th.job = t.job AND th.tdate = t.tdate)
WHERE
    CONVERT(TIME(0), th.modtime) >= CONVERT(TIME(0), t.disptime)
    AND th.moddate >= t.dispdate
    AND th.description LIKE '%Changed Pick-Up Facility%'
    AND th.description NOT LIKE '%From Giles County%'
    AND t.dispdate > '2023-01-01'
```

Comment: Try checking if it exists in the Trip History ADD something like this: AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Trip_History AS th2
    WHERE th2.job = th.job
    AND th2.dispdate = th.dispdate
    AND th2.modtime < th.modtime
)

Comment: Looking at the data (you have shown) `distinct` would suffice

Comment: It looks like you just need to change the first line of your query to `SELECT DISTINCT t.job, t.dispdate, t.description, t.who`. At the moment, presumably your DISTINCT is still returning the other rows because they do have distinct values for th.moddate and th.moddtime

Comment: Move the `t` conditions from WHERE to ON if you want true LEFT JOIN result. As it is now you get regular INNER JOIN result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data shown, you should remove th.moddate and td.modtime from the first line of your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.job, t.dispdate, t.disptime, th.description, th.who
FROM Trip_History as th
LEFT JOIN Trips t ON (th.job = t.job AND th.tdate = t.tdate)
WHERE
    CONVERT(TIME(0), th.modtime) >= CONVERT(TIME(0), t.disptime)
    AND th.moddate >= t.dispdate
    AND th.description LIKE '%Changed Pick-Up Facility%'
    AND th.description NOT LIKE '%From Giles County%'
    AND t.dispdate > '2023-01-01'
```

At the moment, presumably your DISTINCT is still returning the other rows because they do have distinct values for th.moddate and th.modtime

Answer (score 0):

If you're needing completely unique rows, you can use the Distinct like Matt has referenced but another option would be to use the GROUP BY functionality which will allow you to get the same data but it gives you the flexibility to do things like aggregation if required;

```
SELECT t.job, t.dispdate, t.disptime, th.description, th.who
FROM Trip_History as th
LEFT JOIN Trips t ON (th.job = t.job AND th.tdate = t.tdate)
WHERE
    CONVERT(TIME(0), th.modtime) >= CONVERT(TIME(0), t.disptime)
    AND th.moddate >= t.dispdate
    AND th.description LIKE '%Changed Pick-Up Facility%'
    AND th.description NOT LIKE '%From Giles County%'
    AND t.dispdate > '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY t.job, t.dispdate, t.disptime, th.description, th.who
```